How to Sign-Out from Server Auth.js v5
I'm encountering a problem with the user sign-out functionality in my Next js 14 application. I've implemented a custom OAuth solution using Auth.js v5 on the client-side (React) and a .NET server. The issue is that when I click the sign-out button on the client-side, it successfully signs out the user locally, but it doesn't log out the user from the server.
I am not sure how to SignOut on server-side.
Client-side Code (React):
import { signIn, signOut } from "@/lib/auth"
import { Button } from "./ui/button"

export function SignOut(props: React.ComponentPropsWithRef<typeof Button>) {
  return (
    <form
      onSubmit={async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        await signOut();
      }}
      className="w-full"
    >
      <Button variant="ghost" className="w-full p-0" {...props}>
        Sign Out
      </Button>
    </form>
  )
}

Code used from this example: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example
Server-side Logout Method (C#):
[ActionName(nameof(Logout)), HttpPost("~/connect/logout"), ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> LogoutPost()
{
    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
    return SignOut(
        authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        properties: new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            RedirectUri = "/"
        });
}

Next.js Authentication Configuration (TypeScript):
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import "next-auth/jwt"
import { Provider } from 'next-auth/providers'
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"

export default function OwnIdentityProvider(options: any): Provider {
  return {
    id: "chirp-spa",
    name: "Chirp SPA Client",
    type: "oidc",
    ...
    profile: (profile: any) => {
      return {
        id: profile.sub,
        email: profile.email,
        name: profile.name
      }
    },
    clientId: process.env.AUTH_IDENTITY_ID as string,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_IDENTITY_SECRET as string,
  }
}

const config: NextAuthConfig = {
  theme: { logo: "https://authjs.dev/img/logo-sm.png" },
  providers: [
    OwnIdentityProvider({})
  ],
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  events: {
    async signOut() {
      console.log("User signed out from client");
    },
  },
  experimental: {
    enableWebAuthn: true,
  }
};

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)

declare module "next-auth" {
  interface Session {
    accessToken?: string
  }
}

declare module "next-auth/jwt" {
  interface JWT {
    accessToken?: string
  }
}

Any help will be appreciated, or a workaround with this?
